# SQL Compact 4.0 and Entity Framework 4.0: Image/Blob limits?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

A while back, I tried using SQL Compact 3.5 SP1 with Entity Framework 4.0. One of the problems I ran into was a size restriction on image/blob objects (something like 8K) that made the type pretty useless. Does anyone know if this problem has been fixed with the release of SQL Compact 4.0? In other words, If I am using EF4 with SQL Compact 4.0, what are the size limits of the objects I can store? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binary/varbinary formats are still limited to 8k.  But [Image can have up to 2^30-1 bytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx) in the new version.